# Proof that this equation is correct

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Using a truth table I had no problems to proof, that this equation is correct.
But how can I transform the first part to get to the second?
I tried using de morgan but I never made it.
Can anyone give me advice?

[image: Equation]

Comment: What does it mean for two truths to be equal?  The truths "usually grass looks green," and "the Earth revolves around the sun", I think, have the same truth value.  But do those truths stand as equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\neg p \wedge q \rightarrow r =$$
First we know that $A\rightarrow B$ is equivalent with $\neg A\vee B$ thus.
$$\neg(\neg p \wedge q) \vee r  =$$
Now use de morgan:
$$ (p \vee \neg q) \vee r =$$
Switch place between $r$ and $(p \vee \neg q)$ and notice that $r$ is equivalent with $\neg \neg r$.
$$\neg \neg r \vee (p \vee \neg q) =$$
Now again use that $A\rightarrow B$ is equivalent with $\neg A\vee B$ and we reach our conclusion.
$$\neg r \rightarrow (p \vee \neg q)$$

Answer (score 2):

The contrapositive of the first one is $\lnot r\to\lnot(\lnot p\land q)$, which equals the second expression.